# How to show data from JQuery into html <p>tag

Tags: jquery, html

There are some html `p` tag code at below:

```
<div class="row">
    <h5 class="col-md-3">Status: </h5><p id = "status" class="col-md-9"></p>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <h5 class="col-md-3">Block: </h5><p id = "block" class="col-md-9"></p>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$.each(data.txDetails, function(key, val) {
    if(key == 'status') {
        $('#'+key).find('input[value="'+val+'"]').attr('checked', 'checked');
    }
    else {
        $('#'+key).val(val);
    }
});
```

I would like to ask about how JQuery data will show on the html `p` tag? I'm very sure that my `data.txDetails` have data. The keys of the `data.txDetails` are same as `p` tag id. But then, there is no value to show on the `p` tag. how to solve it? Thanks in advance

Comment: First there is no input in your `p`, second it would be `$('#'+key).text(val);` not `$('#'+key).val(val);`

Comment: Also check you aren't using the same `id` multiple times, as it's invalid. Your loop implies that there may be.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `.html()` or `.text()` instead of `.val()` to insert into html. `.val()` is used for input fields not html tags such as `<p>`

`.text()` is the safer option as it will convert html tags to text which prevents XSS

Comment: Oic, thanks for the info. It works once changing to .text().

Comment: If this answer has helped you, please consider 'accepting' it; This will mark your question as solved, and also reward both you and the answerer some reputation - [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1):

- `.val()` use for read or modify the form element of value
- `.html()` use for modifying elements for reading the HTML Tags
- `.text()` use for read or modify the text content elements

  > You should use `.text()` or `.html()` instead of using `.val()`

```
$('#'+key).text(val);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like ,

```
$('#'+key).attr('value',val);
```

or

```
$('#'+key).html(val);
```

or

```
$('#'+key).append(val);
```